# Sql var char going to else every time

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to change 2 into Complete and 2 is a varchar value
but every time it goes in the else clause

```
CASE [consent_complete]
  WHEN  '2'  THEN 'Complete'  
  ELSE 'IN Complete'
END AS  'Complete?'
```

Comment: What is the datatype for [consent_complete]?

Comment: The data type is var char

Comment: What are the actual values in consent_complete? If it is a varchar and you have the value '2' it is impossible to hit the else from the code you posted.

Comment: Please show us  the results of the following: select consent_complete from <insert the rest of the code here>. Your problem may be that the query doesn't return any results where that field has the value of 2

Comment: The query you have looks ok. That is why everyone is asking about the data. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c896d/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect your data has whitespaces and/or `\0` character at the end:

```
SELECT ...
   CASE  
     WHEN LEFT(LTRIM(RTRIM([consent_complete])),1) = '2' THEN 'Complete'  
     ELSE 'Incomplete'
   END AS  [Complete?]
FROM ...
```

Also you should sanitize your data `TRIM` whitespaces and `REPLACE` `\0` character.

Comment: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '2
' to data type int.

Comment: This is no different than the OPs query.

Comment: Could be leading spaces I suppose. Equality checks in sql server will ignore trailing spaces though. :)

Comment: @lad2025 it is going to the else statement

Comment: @Alexander then post the direct result where your `2` gets `Incomplete`

Comment: @Lamak I get only 0 or 2 I am trying to convert 2 into Complete and everything else into Incomplete

Comment: @Alexander you are saying: `it is going to the else statement`, so you need to do `SELECT consent_complete, CASE ....` and post here where you have a `consent_complete` of 2 that goes to `incomplete`

Comment: @Alexander `SELECT LEN(consent_complete), DATALENGTH(consent_complete)` Let me guess `\0` character

Comment: @Alexander Check `CASE  
     WHEN LEFT(LTRIM(RTRIM([consent_complete])),1) = '2' THEN 'Complete'  
     ELSE 'Incomplete'
   END AS  [Complete?]`

Comment: @lad2025 thnx your last comment worked post it as answer ill check it